# Can you pull the connectionString for a log4net AdoNetAppender from elsewhere in a web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, log4net

I already have a db connection string in my web.config file. I scanned the log4net docs, but can't seem to find a way to use it within the log4net section of my web.config file. Is is possible to do something like this?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; ..." />
</connectionStrings>

<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <connectionString connectionStringName="connStr"/>
      ...
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Create a class that extends `AdoNetAppender` - say, `WebAppAdoNetAppender`.  Implement the `ConnectionString` property in that class, and retrieve the connection string from your web.config file in that property setter.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="MyApp.WebAppAdoNetAppender">
    ...
```

...

```
public class WebAppAdoNetAppender : log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender
{
    public new string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return base.ConnectionString; }
        set { base.ConnectionString = ...   }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stefan Egli's link indicates that a parameter doesn't yet exist.  For the time being, this seems like the best way to go about it.  Thanks Mr. Petrotta!

Comment: How and where would I load/call/use this class? I'm just getting started with log4net and I'm finding the documentation a little sparse. I'm running this in a Quartz.NET job, which instantiates the logger for me. How would I replace the default logger with my own subclass? Thanks.

Answer (score 50):

It is possible to use a DB connection string specified in web.config without creating a new class, though you would need to use log4net build that hasn't been released yet. It can be downloaded from SVN repository http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/

Your config will look as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=localhost; ..." />
</connectionStrings>

<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionStringName value="connStr" />
      ...
</log4net>
```

Please note that `connectionType` still needs to be specified.

Comment: This is now available in the latest release, 1.2.11.  Works fine.

Answer (score 5):

fyi this will be implemented in 1.2.11 according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-88). however I have no idea when they are going to release it.

Comment: sounds like the feature I want is forthcoming

Answer (score 5):

the answers above all do not work. i got another solution for this, i tried and it worked:

```
private static void ConfigureLog4Net()
{
    Hierarchy hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
    if(hierarchy != null && hierarchy.Configured)
    {
        foreach(IAppender appender in hierarchy.GetAppenders())
        {
           if(appender is AdoNetAppender)
           {
               var adoNetAppender = (AdoNetAppender)appender;
               adoNetAppender.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGKEY"].ToString();
               adoNetAppender.ActivateOptions(); //Refresh AdoNetAppenders Settings
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[How i can use the connectionString of the current website for log4Net instead of configuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723051/how-i-can-use-the-connectionstring-of-the-current-website-for-log4net-instead-of)

Comment: I also couldn't get the code above to work *and this did*.

For me though, I had to make sure to have a blank ConnectionString in the config:  <connectionstring value="" />

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017 (log4net `2.0.8.0`), the following works:

```
public class MyAdoNetAppender : AdoNetAppender
{
    public MyAdoNetAppender()
    {
        ConnectionString = ...
    }
}


<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="MyApp.MyAdoNetAppender">
```

(Very similar to @Michael Petrotta's answer)