# connectionStringName in log4net

Tags: web-config, log4net, connection-string, log4net-configuration, adonetappender

Is the `connectionStringName` property of log4net pulling connection strings from `web.config` as well as from `app.config`?

I've tried to use it, but for some reason it did not work.

I've put some connection string named 'Logs' in my `web.config` and then added in my `log4net.config` an `AdoNetAppender` with a `connectiongStringName` set to 'Logs', but it did not seem to work.

Could someone provide some working example of how to use this feature?

Thank you

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441359/can-you-pull-the-connectionstring-for-a-log4net-adonetappender-from-elsewhere-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`log4net` uses 
`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[];` to read the connectionstring from the configuration file.

So as long as you specify ConnectionStrings in your app/web.config file like below, it should be all right:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="<ConnectionStringName>" connectionString="<actual connection string>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

Comment: what if I am having an appsettings.json instead of web.config?