# How i can use the connectionString of the current website for log4Net instead of configuring

Tags: c#, log4net, connection-string

I use log4Net for my system's log. The connectionString node is mandatory if the appender type is the AdoNetAppender in Log4Net. However, I already have a connectionString in my website where I use Log4Net.

How can I use the connStr of the website for log4Net instead of configuring the same connstr again in the log4net config file?

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441359/can-you-pull-the-connectionstring-for-a-log4net-adonetappender-from-elsewhere-in

Answer (score 44):

It's quite simple, you just need to replace the appender `connectionString` configuration.

In place of the connection string:

```
<connectionString value="[Complete Connection]" />
```

You just use the `connectionStringName` configuration:

```
<connectionStringName value="ApplicationConnection" />
```

And then you have your application connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="ApplicationConnection" connectionString="Connection" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Unfortunately you must have the `connectionType` with the connectionStringName, example:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_Oracle" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <connectionType value="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionStringName value="ApplicationConnection" />
...
```

Comment: Does this work with encrypted connection strings?  I got it working with plain-text, but the logging stops when I encrypt the connection string

Comment: This worked perfect for me! And since I use publish profiles for different environments, this totally made my day, as it greatly simplified what I had to do to make the configuration work

Answer (score 22):

You can update ConnectionString of AdoNetAppender dynamically, after you have configured log4net for your website, usually in the Global.asax. After your call to configure the log4net using `XmlConfigutor()` or something.. you can call below method which checks for all AdoNetAppenders and update the connectionString required.

```
private static void ConfigureLog4Net()
{
    Hierarchy hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
    if(hierarchy != null && hierarchy.Configured)
    {
        foreach(IAppender appender in hierarchy.GetAppenders())
        {
           if(appender is AdoNetAppender)
           {
               var adoNetAppender = (AdoNetAppender)appender;
               adoNetAppender.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGKEY"].ToString();
               adoNetAppender.ActivateOptions(); //Refresh AdoNetAppenders Settings
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can now use the ConnectionStringName property of the AdoNetAppender do point it to a named connectionString in your app or web.config file:

[AdoNetAppender.ConnectionStringName Property](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_AdoNetAppender_ConnectionStringName.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by inheriting AdoNetAppender.

- 1) Create a class that inherits from AdoNetAppender.
- 2) Next create a ConnectionStringName property that will set the Log4Net ConnectionString property to a connection string that is retrieved by the .Net ConfigurationManager.
- 3) Create a ConnectionStringName entry in the AdoNetAppender section of  your config file which maps to an existing connectionString in the connectionStrings section of your config file.

See the below "Ken Burkhardt" blog for details.

http://kenny-bu.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-connection-string-name-with.html

Comment: Thanks minmin, i cannot open the link you provied what you told me should be found from the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441359/can-you-pull-the-connectionstring-for-a-log4net-adonetappender-from-elsewhere-in. BUT it doesnot work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by writing a custom ADO.NET appender and overriding the connection string:

```
public new string ConnectionString {
    get { 
        return base.ConnectionString; 
    }

    //you could set your own connection string here
    set { 
        base.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["Sql"].
            ConnectionString; 
    }
}
```

You could visit http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/03/12/how-to-write-custom-ado-net-appender-for-log4net/ for a complete example

Comment: i used the way by Narayan Akhade. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible in version 1.2.11. Here is the link to the issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-88

Comment: thanks Stefan i used the way provided by @Narayan Akhade