# Log4Net connection string read out of web.config

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I'm working with Log4Net in a project, with the 1.0 framework.

I'm trying to look for a method to read the string connection from a file o other place that is not the web.config, for security issues.

Is there a way to do that kind of configuration?

Comment: if you are worried about security issues, have you tried encrypting the connection string in the config file. you could also store the connection string inside of a database and encrypt that as well but that's what the web.config file is there for. I would not store it in a file.. whats there to stop someone from finding the file location?

Comment: yes, the thing is that is a money trasaccion aplication and if we live the connection really easy to find to the out side, is like open the door to the word, the string is there for the configuration requirement of log4net, i´m gone try to encrypt thanks :)

Comment: it´s not the same, but it´s similar

Answer (score 0):

You can access log4net's appenders and modify your database logger at runtime. The code [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723051/how-i-can-use-the-connectionstring-of-the-current-website-for-log4net-instead-of) should do the trick.